# mailto: links in Opera GX

Tags: browser, opera, mailto

I've been trying to put my own mailto: link on default, for me to click it and instantly move to composing the email. In Opera GX there is no setting for that. Yandex browser support suggests this code:
`javascript:window.navigator.registerProtocolHandler("mailto","https://mail.yandex.ru/compose?mailto=%s","Яндекс.Почта")`
(https://browser.yandex.ru/help/useful-features/special-links.html)

I've tried to run it in Opera, but links doesn't do anything (Opera is default for emails in Windows settings). I also tried running `javascript:window.navigator.registerProtocolHandler("mailto","https://e.mail.ru/compose/?mailto=%s","Mail.ru")`, because that's the service that I actually want to use, browser asked permission for the site to open email links, I allowed, and nothing happened. What do I do now for these links to work?

Answer (score 0):

opera://settings/handlers -
You can set it up there.

Opera GX also suggests to set up mailto for mail services like mail.google.com when you visit them.